# mysqli_query single query gerenating PHP fatal error: Allowed memory size exhausted

Tags: php, windows, mysqli, memory-leaks, xampp

I have a Mysql table (named "base") with **3 million records**, which is composed of only **3 int(10) fields**.

[image]

When I try to run this simple query `$result = mysqli_query($db, 'SELECT * FROM base')`, php shows the error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted
>   (tried to allocate 10485768 bytes) in C:\xampp\htdocs\combina.php on
>   line 17

I think mysqli_query should not load all the table records into memory, right?

So why the memory overflow?

I'm using **XAMPP installation on Windows 10, PHP 7.2.**

Here is the code:

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "comb";

$db = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if (!$db) {
    die("Falha na conexão: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
$result = mysqli_query($db, 'SELECT * FROM base');
```

Comment: The only code in the file is `$result = mysqli_query($db, 'SELECT * FROM base')`?

Comment: I added the code now in question

Comment: There's no `fetch` though?

Comment: The error occurs precisely on the line `mysqli_query($db, 'SELECT * FROM base')`. I did not understand your question.

Comment: You don't fetch the result object?

Comment: I don't know how to do this. What am I missing?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176842/discussion-between-rogerio-dec-and-user3783243).

Answer (score 1):

I researched and realized that the `mysqli_query` command actually loads ALL records into RAM. That is, for large tables, it will actually generate a memory limitation.

The solution I found was to use the combination of [mysqli_real_query](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli.real-query.php) (which will activate the query **without loading all the records in RAM**, [mysqli_use_result](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli.use-result.php) (which will return the resulting object **not buffered** ) and finally [mysqli_fetch_row](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli-result.fetch-row.php) which will read the result line by line.

In this way the solution to the presented problem would be more or less:

```
$db = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
mysqli_real_query($db, 'SELECT * FROM base');
$result = mysqli_use_result($db);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
    ...
```